# How to make my url work, by calling in my method en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem in my code, in my method `componentDidMount`, when I call my variable URL in my `this.handleClick(url)` it makes me indecisive, but when I create a `console.log` from `url` it works, it generates a link when I click any of my buttons!

How do i get my URL to work in `this.handleclick()`?

```js
const { Component } = React;       // import React, { Component } from 'react';
const { Button } = ReactBootstrap; // import Button from './components/Button';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      capital: "",
      flag: "",
      population: 0,
    }
  }

  handleClick = (country) => {
    fetch(country)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({
          name: json[0].name,
          capital: json[0].capital,
          flag: json[0].flag,
          population: json[0].population,
          region: json[0].region,
        })
      );

    console.log(this.state)
    console.log(country)
  }

  componentDidMount(click) {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${click}`;

    this.handleClick()// here i have to call

    console.log(url)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <p> name= {this.state.name}</p>
        <p> capital= {this.state.capital}</p>
        <p> flag= {this.state.flag}</p>
        <p> population= {this.state.population}</p>
        <p> region= {this.state.region}</p>
        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'france')}>France</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'brazil')}>Brazil</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount.bind(this, 'croatia')}>Croatia</Button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app")); // export default App;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@1/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: * I click a of my Button !

Comment: why are you binding ComponentDidMount to click??

Comment: so that when I click on button this generates me a linked to the country, it is to avoid that I make a request for chays country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `handleClick` directly.

componentDidMount is a react [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), don't bind it to click events!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Button from './components/Button';


class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      capital: "",
      flag: "",
      population: 0,

    }
  }

  handleClick = (click) => {

    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${click}`;


    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>

        this.setState({
          name: json[0].name,
          capital: json[0].capital,
          flag: json[0].flag,
          population: json[0].population,
          region: json[0].region,
        })

      );

    console.log(this.state)
    console.log(country)


  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <p> name= {this.state.name}</p>
        <p> capital= {this.state.capital}</p>
        <p> flag= {this.state.flag}</p>
        <p> population= {this.state.population}</p>
        <p> region= {this.state.region}</p>
        <Button onClick={this. handleClick.bind(this, 'france')}>France</Button>
        <Button onClick={this. handleClick.bind(this, 'brazil')}>Brazil</Button>
        <Button onClick={this. handleClick.bind(this, 'croatia')}>Croatia</Button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks but why did you remove componentDidMount?
(I have to use the method for my exercise)

Comment: cause once you use onClick handler, there was not need for it in the attached code

Comment: ha okay, I get it; I tested the code but it doesn't give me exactly what I want, it does me when I click on France it gives me an object on the brazil, and when I do on the brazil it gives me an object on the croaztie etc ...

Comment: @sakura If you want the component to load data on mount you will have to add the `componentDidMount` method again, which can then call `handleClick`. However, since the user has not clicked any button yet, you will have to provide a default value. For example: `componentDidMount() { handleClick("usa"); }` This will load the USA data before the user clicked any button.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` lifecycle method doesn't accept any parameter, remove the `click` parameter, and call your `handleClick` method ordinary

Comment: yes i delete thanks, i now understood that in this method only squeezes for life cycles, thanks